# Laravel queue worker Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I switch from the sync driver to the database driver for the queue and I been getting this error ErrorException
Trying to get property 'id' of non-object. I have no idea where this error is happening since everything works with the sync driver. I tried to find some solutions to this problem but I am unable to find anything that leads me in the right direction.

I know what the error means but it just does not make since that I am getting this error.

Comment: Well it won't make sense to us either based on that description only. We need to see some code.

Comment: This is a shot in the dark, but try removing the serialize models trait that is automatically used.

Comment: Are you setting anything as `$this->foo` in the job, but not declaring `private/public $foo` in the class?

Comment: Somewhere you have  e.g. `$model->id` and the `$model` does not exist. Until you give us your code, we can't be any more descriptive or explain why or how this is happening.